# default username gone only can login as guest （16.04）

Tags: 16.04, passwd-file

Today I did a stupid thing. I used `sudo gedit /etc/passwd` changed

```
x:1000:1000:kai:/home/linuxidc:/bin/bash
```

this from `1000` to `0`.

Then after I restart only can login as a guest. No default username in the list.
Please help get the default username back.

Comment: And what were trying achieve when you did this?

Comment: Boot from a Live stick or DVD/CD and revert the change.

Comment: @thomas can you show how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without booting to a LiveUSB or LiveCD/DVD, we can actually borrow *some* of the steps from [this answer on resetting a lost password](https://askubuntu.com/a/24024/10616) to get to a recovery console, and then make changes to the system and reboot afterwards.

To summarize the steps (everything from 1 to 4 is from the other question; 5 and 6 are the different steps to do):

(1) Boot up the system, and after you see the BIOS screen press and hold "Shift" - you'll get the GRUB prompt.

(2) Use the 'recovery mode' option for your kernel - if it doesn't show up it's probably under the section for "Other Ubuntu versions" or one of the other items on Grub.

(3) Once in recovery mode, select the 'root' option by using the down arrow on your keyboard, and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  You'll end up with a command line prompt for the `root` user.

(4) Remount your system as read/write with this command: `mount -o remount,rw /`

(5) Edit your `/etc/passwd` file with `nano` (use this command: `nano /etc/passwd`).  Once you've edited the specific line for your user and reset it to `1000` for the UID and GID, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

(6) You should now be at the `root` terminal prompt again.  Reboot with `shutdown -r now` or `reboot`.

You should then be able to login again, and have fixed your blunder.  Don't go messing with your UID or GID, because setting yourself to `0` will break things and is ***horribly insecure and should never be done.***  (The `0` UID is for `root`, and `root` alone - DO NOT USE IT FOR ANY OTHER USER!)

Comment: Hi man, can you please tell me how to write the order to Remount your system as read/write. And how to  Edit your /etc/passwd file with nano.I am a new user of ubuntu. thanks a lot

Comment: @kindlong I already do - it's the command at the end of the line after the period.

Comment: Also good to point out that _uid_ 0 is reserved for root only. You can't use that uid again.

Comment: @kindlong You're welcome!  Feel free to upvote my answer and accept it if it solved your problem!  (That way the system knows the question has been resolved)

Comment: @kindlong if the answer solved your problem kindly accept it with the accept button to the left of the answer